# SQL: Select lowest value that doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In TableA I have an int column.

Is it possible using only a select statement to select the minimum value in the column that DOES NOT EXIST and is greater then 0?

For example, if the col has the values 1,2,9 the select statement will return 3.
If the col has 9,10,11 it will return 1.

I can achieve this using a temp table or using a loop, but I'm wondering if I can do it using just a select statement?

Comment: Why do you need this? If you want to reuse IDs, it's normally a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
min(nt.id)
from numbertable nt
left outer join originaldata od
on nt.id=od.id
where od.id is null
```

have a number table that goes from 1 to your max value (or higher)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MIN(t1.ID+1) as 'MinID'
FROM table t1 LEFT JOIN table t2
On t1.ID+1=t2.ID
Where t2.OtherField IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x + 1 "val"
EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT x "val"
ORDER BY "val" ASC
LIMIT 1
```

What about this?

Comment: +1 from me for the idea; three notes - DISTINCT does not seem to be necessary and you should have put the FROM clauses. Plus, it will not work for the second example (you might have to union the first part with SELECT 1).

Comment: This will return the first free value that is one more than an existing value. So it doesn't solve my 2 examples unfortunately and i can't see how I can change it so it does

Comment: So… as said by Unreason, `(SELECT DISTINCT x+1 "val" UNION SELECT 1) EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT x "val" ORDER BY "val" ASC LIMIT 1` should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Min(id)
FROM   (SELECT 1 id
        FROM   tablea
        WHERE  1 NOT IN (SELECT id
                         FROM   tablea)
        UNION
        SELECT id + 1 id
        FROM   tablea
        WHERE  id + 1 NOT IN (SELECT id
                              FROM   tablea)) AS min_ids;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:(Updated)

```
    declare @dummy varchar(10)  ;

set @dummy =(select top(1) id from  dbo.b) 

if(   @dummy= '1')
begin
select top(1)l.id + 1 as start
from dbo.b  as l
  left outer join dbo.b  as r on l.id + 1 = r.id
where r.id is null
end
else 
begin
select '1'
end
```

Comment: This will return the first free value that is one more than an existing value. So it doesn't solve my 2 examples unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
declare @TestTable table (
    col int
)

/* Test Case 1: 1,2,9 */
insert into @TestTable
    (col)
    select 1 union all select 2 union all select 9

SELECT MinValue = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(t2.col),0)+1
                      FROM @TestTable t2 
                     WHERE t2.col < t1.col)
 FROM @TestTable t1
 WHERE t1.col - 1 NOT IN (SELECT col FROM @TestTable)
   AND t1.col - 1 > 0

delete from @TestTable

/* Test Case 2: 9,10,11 */
insert into @TestTable
    (col)
    select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11

SELECT MinValue = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(t2.col),0)+1
                      FROM @TestTable t2 
                     WHERE t2.col < t1.col)
 FROM @TestTable t1
 WHERE t1.col - 1 NOT IN (SELECT col FROM @TestTable)
   AND t1.col - 1 > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684106/find-the-smallest-unused-number-in-sql-server/37409483#37409483):

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) + 1 AS firstfree
FROM (SELECT id FROM table UNION SELECT 0) a
LEFT JOIN table b ON b.id = a.id + 1
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

This handles all cases I can think of - including no existing records at all.

The only thing I don't like about this solution is that additional conditions have to be included twice, like that:

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) + 1 AS firstfree
FROM (SELECT id FROM table WHERE column = 4711 UNION SELECT 0) a
LEFT JOIN table b ON b.column = 4711 AND b.id = a.id + 1
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Please also notice the comments about locking and concurrency - the requirement to fill gaps is in most cases bad design and can cause problems. However, I had a good reason to do it: the IDs are to be printed and typed by humans and we don't want to have IDs with many digits after some time, while all the low ones are free...