# SQL conditionally select different aggergates

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a table `T`, that has one attribute, `A`, an integer.

How can I make the SQL query return `MAX(T) + 1` if `T` contains a 5 and `MAX(T) + 2` if it doesn't?

Comment: What's the real task behind this strange requirement? PS: what actual DBMS do you use?

Comment: I'm using SQLite. I'm trying to return the smallest positive integer that's not present in a sequence of positive integers. e.g. return 3 if the sequence is 2, 6, 7. Return 5 if the sequence is 1, 2, 3, 4. Return 2 if the sequence is 3, 4.

Comment: "return 3 if the sequence is 2, 6, 7." --- why not 1? "Return 2 if the sequence is 3, 4" --- why not 1?

Comment: I think you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684106/find-the-smallest-unused-number-in-ms-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(a) + CASE WHEN (5 IN (SELECT a FROM t)) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS max_plus_something FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(A) + MIN(CASE A WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS NewA FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the chance to test many cases but i think this can do what you want.

```
declare @MinPosNI int;
set @MinPosNI = 1;
select @MinPosNI = case when (A - @MinPosNI) > 0 then @MinPosNI else A + 1 end from T     where A > 0 order by A 
select @MinPosNI
```