# Obtain the missing number

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the smallest unused number in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684106/find-the-smallest-unused-number-in-sql-server)

I have this table in Sql server

```
ID |  LetterID | LetterName
```

> ID => int and identity
>
> LetterID => int and unique and NotNull
>
> LetterName => string

`LetterID` fill from my C# application and user set number for it.for example 1,2,3,4,5,...,100,.. (increment an unit for each row) and now my `LetterID` is `100` but Sometimes user delete one row from table for example delete row where `LetterID` is `50`, now for insert new row (in application) I suggested to him `LetterID` chose `50`, How can I get the missing numbers from table?

Comment: Why do you want to fill those gaps?

Comment: Are we worried about multi-user and locking here? i.e. do you have to lock that 50 from other users?

Comment: Why do you want to fill those gaps? – Tim Schmelter => Yes

Comment: @hamidrezamansouri - Tim's question was **why?** The answer "Yes" doesn't fit. And if you want to reply to someone, start your comment with `@`, their username and a space. They'll get notified of your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the blank/missing row

```
SELECT TOP 1 x.LetterID +1 
FROM tablename x
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tablename xx WHERE xx.LetterID  = x.LetterID  + 1)
ORDER BY x.LetterID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var output =  Enumerable.Range(1, list.Max(item => item.LetterID))
          .Except(list.Select(item => item.LetterID))
```

Comment: Can you please explain further about this source?

Comment: this code Except two list.is code optimize for high row?

Comment: @hamidrezamansouri: this source use LINQ to Entities

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.ID, t1.LetterID-1 
from yourtable t1
    left join yourtable t2 
on t1.LetterID = t2.LetterID+1
and t1.ID = t2.ID
where t2.ID is null
and t1.LetterID>(select MIN(LetterID) from yourtable where ID = t1.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(
  select max(LetterID) as id from your_table
  union all
  select id-1 from cte where id>1
)
select cte.id as LetterID
from cte
left join your_table yt on cte.id=yt.LetterID
where yt.id is null
order by cte.id
```