# Doctrine DQL: Find lowest integer value available

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, dql, scalar

I want to write a DQL query with Doctrine that allow me to find lowest integer available in a specific column.

Table(ABC)

```
A              B
----------------
0              M
1              P
2              T
4              X
5              L
7              C
```

I want a single scalar result.
In this case, (SELECT LowestValueAvailable(A) FROM ABC) = 3.

I know how to write it in basic SQL, but I can't figure this out in DQL.
This would be the exact SQL request I want to DQLize : [Find the smallest unused number in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684106/find-the-smallest-unused-number-in-sql-server)

Thank you.

Comment: `MIN` function?

Comment: Won't work, because it would return 0. :) I need 3.

Comment: Put your working SQL query in the post.

Comment: See. for working SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684106/find-the-smallest-unused-number-in-sql-server

Comment: Kinda hard to figure this out, isn't it? Doctrine allow us to write SQL, but it's unsafe. So if someone figure this out, It would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Read [Doctrine Query Language](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Comment: In your model Column A data are integer or string values?

Comment: Question is not sense, lower value in your example is 0 so if you apply MIN() function that is the function you have to apply to get the min value then  you will get as expected 0. Why you expect 3?. Maybe I'm living in another planet where 0 > 3  ???. Please clearify your question or prepare to receive down votes

Comment: I want the LOWEST integer NOT present in column. with minimum allowed = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A as property that maps A column in database:

```
$dql = ' SELECT MIN(e.A) as minValue
         FROM YourBundle:YourEntity e
       ';
$result = $yourEntityManager->createQuery($dql)->getScalarResult();
```

With this query you get `minValue` in column A. If you need type `var_dump($result)`

In doctrine docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#aggregate-functions

Comment: This isn't what I wanted, you responded too fast. "Find the smallest UNUSED number in DQL" with constraint, of course, cannot be negative or unsigned if you want.

Comment: Ok, title of question is confusing for me. If you only want know the value of the number one approach could be get all distinct values using a dql query and process later the result.